# Query mongodb based on form parameter

Tags: mongodb, express, ejs

I am trying to query mongodb based on form parameter.

```
<form action="/word/" method="GET">
    Get quote:<input type="text" name="word" value="">
    <br><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

But in my server.js, when i try to console.log, i get back undefined.

```
app.get('/word', function(req, res) {
console.log(req.body.word);
})
```

Should i place a url parameter like this?

```
<form action="/word/<%= quote %>" method="GET">
    Get quote:<input type="text" name="word" value="">
    <br><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

And in server.js

```
app.get('/word/:quote', function(req, res) {
console.log(req.body.word);
})
```

Comment: I suggest removing all mention of `mongodb` from this question (including the tags) as it doesn't appear to be relevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 3 main options available to you.

Option 1 is to use a form with a GET request. The `<input>` values will be appended onto the URL, something like `/word/?word=value`. On the server you'd need something like this:

```
app.get('/word', function(req, res) {
    console.log(req.query.word);
});
```

Option 2 is to use a form with a POST request, which defaults to using a `content-type` (`enctype`) of `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. That encodes the `<input>` the same way as the GET request but instead of putting it on the end of the URL it puts it in the request body.

On the server you'd do something like this:

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));

app.post('/word', function(req, res) {
    console.log(req.body.word);
});
```

Option 3 is to encode it into the URL like `/word/value` but that would require some client-side JavaScript to craft the URL just before the `<form>` is submitted (assuming that the URL is dependent on the value in the `<input>`, if it doesn't depend on that then no problem). The server in that case would be:

```
app.get('/word/:quote', function(req, res) {
    console.log(req.params.quote);
});
```

Note that each of the 3 options uses a different property for the parsed data: `req.query`, `req.body` or `req.params`.

There are other options available. If you're using AJAX you could pick whatever format you want, possibly one of those above or some alternative like JSON, which could then be parsed using `bodyParser.json`.

For more about `bodyParser` see:

https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/body-parser.html

Note that Express 4.16.0 introduces `express.json` and `express.urlencoded` which can be used instead of `bodyParser`.

Comment: Now to query the mongodb is this right? User.findOne({name:req.query.word},

Answer (score 0):

You should be using the `post` method instead of `get`
A body cannot be sent with a get request.

The body is going to be sent with a mime type of `multipart/form-data`
So you're going to need to use some middleware like [multer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer) to parse it.